# Scraping a wikipedia table

Tags: r, web-scraping

I scraped a wikipedia table using r

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City"
nyc <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

And want to save the values into a new dataframe.

Output

```
Area           population
468.484 sq mi  8,336,817
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from OP's example output they want the table given at a different xpath to that which they provided in the question. Please see the following workflow, note: names have been set manually to save the hassle of formatting the strings from rows:

```
# Initialise package in session: rvest => .GlobalEnv()
library(rvest)

# Store the url scalar: url => character vector 
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City"

# Scrape the table and store it memory: nyc => data.frame
nyc <- 
  url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/table[3]') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
  data.frame()

# Set the names appropriately: names(nyc) character vector
names(nyc) <- c("borough", "county", "pop_est_2019", 
                "gdp_bill_usd", "gdp_per_cap", 
                "land_area_sq_mi", "land_area_sq_km", 
                "density_pop_sq_mi", "density_pop_sq_km")

# Coerce the vectors to the appropriate type: cleaned => data.frame
cleaned <- data.frame(lapply(nyc[4:nrow(nyc)-1,], function(x){ 
    if(length(grep("\\d+\\,\\d+$|^\\d+\\.\\d+$", x)) > 0){
      as.numeric(trimws(gsub("\\,", "", as.character(x)), "both"))
    }else{ 
      as.factor(x)
      }
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: I used the same approach to scrape the table for Atlanta "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta" but couldn't get it done. I get an error stating "column names must not be duplicated"

Comment: @doll that article doesn't appear to have the same table at the same xpath, so that's why you can't scrape it.

Comment: If my answer does what your initial question requires, it is customary to upvote and accept it.

Comment: I wanted to scrape table[1]

Comment: @doll you need to learn some SO etiquette and make sure your question is clear then. My answer does what your post above asks, for that generally you upvote answers and accept the best the one. No one here is paid to help you. If you have other questions you ask them on a separate post.

Answer (score 3):

You need to choose which table. From the table select needed columns and rows. Assign column names using `setNames` and reset `rownames` by setting them to `NULL`. I'm sure you want `population` column `as.integer`, just use `gsub` before to clean out the non-digits.

I'm not sure about the `html_node` line and left it out.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City"

nyc <- read_html(url)
# nyc <- html_node(nyc, xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]')
nyc <- html_table(nyc, header=TRUE, fill = TRUE)

nyc <- `rownames<-`(
  setNames(nyc[[3]][-c(1:2, 10), 2:3], c("area", "population")), 
  NULL)
nyc <- transform(nyc, population=as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", population)))
nyc
#                area population
# 1             Bronx    1418207
# 2             Kings    2559903
# 3          New York    1628706
# 4            Queens    2253858
# 5          Richmond     476143
# 6  City of New York    8336817
# 7 State of New York   19453561
```